# PHP preg_grep not working?

Tags: php, regex

```
$fileNameMatchRegex = ^a-[0-9]*_b-[0-9]*_c-.*(_d-on)?_((19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))-[0-9]*\.csv$

$fileNames = 

Array  
(
    [0] => index.html
    [1] => a-34234234_b-3271_c-123_d-on_2013-08-12-10.csv
    [2] => a-52342345_b-3271_c-123_d-on_2013-08-12-11.csv
    [3] => a-8764453_b-3271_c-123_d-on_2013-08-12-12.csv
    [4] => a-7654334_b-3271_c-1234_d-on_2013-08-12-4.csv
    [5] => a-3435_b-3271_c-23re_d-on_2013-08-12-5.csv
    [6] => a-909876_b-3271_c-wef2r2_d-on_2013-08-12-6.csv
    [7] => a-345456_b-3271_c-23rwef_d-on_2013-08-12-7.csv
    [8] => a-98765_b-3271_c-23ref_d-on_2013-08-12-8.csv
    [9] => a-098765_b-3271_c-wef2r_d-on_2013-08-12-9.csv
)

$matchingFileNames  = preg_grep ("/".$fileNameMatchRegex."/", $fileNames);
```

This works here...I get a match on 1-9: [regex tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)

Comment: You have to define `$fileNameMatchRegex` before `$matchingFileNames`.

Comment: probably has to do with how you are escaping characters (or not escaping them) in php. the example where it is working is javascript not php. or what @nickb said. or both.

Comment: Sorry nickb...that's not the code order, that's just the values.

Comment: @nathanhayfield: I'm not escaping characters in php...that regex comes from a file. I grab it from a file and just use it in a parameter. $fileNameMatchRegex = $data["filenameregex"];

Comment: Escape your delimiter characters in your actual regex (in other words, use `\/`)

Comment: Enable error reporting for your own sanity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working fine for me

```
    $fileNames = explode(',', "index.html,a-34234234_b-3271_c-123_d-on_2013-08-12-10.csv,a-52342345_b-3271_c-123_d-on_2013-08-12-11.csv,a-8764453_b-3271_c-123_d-on_2013-08-12-12.csv,a-7654334_b-3271_c-1234_d-on_2013-08-12-4.csv,a-3435_b-3271_c-23re_d-on_2013-08-12-5.csv,a-909876_b-3271_c-wef2r2_d-on_2013-08-12-6.csv,a-345456_b-3271_c-23rwef_d-on_2013-08-12-7.csv,a-98765_b-3271_c-23ref_d-on_2013-08-12-8.csv,a-098765_b-3271_c-wef2r_d-on_2013-08-12-9.csv");
    $fileNameMatchRegex = '^a-[0-9]*_b-[0-9]*_c-.*(_d-on)?_((19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))-[0-9]*\.csv$';
    $matchingFileNames  = preg_grep ("#".$fileNameMatchRegex."#", $fileNames);

    print_r($fileNames);
    print_r($matchingFileNames);
```

but i used '#' around the regexp as delimiter, as your regexp included '/',
you proberly just need to escape your '/' or chose a better delimiter

Comment: see it did have to do with escaping things in php. in this case the delimiters...

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer. :-)